# Linkage in C: does GCC follow the C99 spec, or do I not understand the spec?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, linkage

I'm trying to understand the exact behavior of storage class specifiers in C99, and some GCC behavior seems not to follow the spec, unless I misunderstand the spec.  From 6.2.2 (2):

> Within one translation unit, each declaration of an identifier with *internal linkage* denotes the same object or function.

However, I tested GCC (powerpc-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1) with the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int f() {
    static int x = 0;
    return x++;
}
static int g() {
    static int x = 0;
    return x++;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("g() = %i\n", g());
    printf("g() = %i\n", g());
    printf("f() = %i\n", f());
    printf("f() = %i\n", f());
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `-std=c99`, It prints the following:

```
g() = 0
g() = 1
f() = 0
f() = 1
```

If I understand the spec correctly, it should print:

```
g() = 0
g() = 1
f() = 2
f() = 3
```

I understand why GCC would deviate from the spec here, I'm just wondering if there's a deeper explanation for this behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The next paragraph, 6.2.2/3, is important:

> If the declaration of a *file scope identifier* for an object or a function contains the storage-class specifier static, the identifier has internal linkage.

(note the emphasized *file scope identifier*).

Your static variables `x` do not have file scope, they have block scope.

Comment: In other words, each x is local to the function that declares it.

Comment: Thanks.  It's easy to miss words in the spec.

Comment: @Dietrich:  It is.  In fact, it's so easy, I missed the more relevant and important part, which sth posted as an answer.

Answer (score 10):

In 6.2.2 (6) it says:

> The following identifiers have no linkage: *[...]* a block scope
>   identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier extern.

The static variables are block scope identifiers for objects, and they are not declared `extern`. Therefore they have no linkage, especially not internal linkage.